# C# Dynamic Expression Tree for search list using Where (or Any) and generics

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, expression

Currently, I have a working helper function that creates a simple expression to search a generic entity (TEntity) for a search term (single word/phrase). It creates the following expression:

```
q => q.Product.ProductTitle.Contains( searchText: 'red shirt' )
```

I simply need to extend this helper to search each word includes in the search term (e.g. searchText:'red shirt' --> searchTerms:['red','shirt'])

```
var searchTerms = searchText.ToLower().Split( new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).ToList();
searchTerms.Any( s => !q.Product.ProductTitle.ToLower().Contains( s ) )
```

The function is listed below - I have commented code that needs to be completed.

```
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateSearchQuery( List<PropertyInfo> searchPropertiesList, string searchText, SearchType searchType = SearchType.Contains )
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( searchText ) || searchPropertiesList == null || searchPropertiesList.Count <= 0 )
        {
            return null;
        }

        var searchTerms = searchText.ToLower().Split( new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).ToList();
        var searchExpressionList = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
        foreach( var property in searchPropertiesList.Where( x => x.GetCustomAttributes( false ).Any( c => c.GetType() != typeof( NotMappedAttribute ) ) ) )
        {
            //search param
            var searchParam = Expression.Parameter( typeof( string ), "s" );

            //search type
            var searchTypeMethod = typeof( string ).GetMethod( searchType.ToString(), new[] { typeof( string ) } );

            //entity expression.
            var entityParam = Expression.Parameter( typeof( TEntity ), "q" );
            var entityProperty = Expression.Property( entityParam, property );
            var entityExpression = Expression.Call(
                Expression.Call( entityProperty, typeof( string ).GetMethod( "ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes ) ),
                searchTypeMethod,
                Expression.Call( searchParam, typeof( string ).GetMethod( "ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes ) )
            );
            var entityPredicateBody = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>( entityExpression, entityParam );

            ////TODO: CONSIDER EACH TERM AND CREATE WHERE/ANY EXPRESSION
            //searchTerms.Any( s => !q.Product.ProductTitle.ToLower().Contains( s ) )
            //var filterExpression = Expression.Call(
            //    typeof( Enumerable ),
            //    "Where",
            //    new[] { typeof( TEntity ) },
            //    searchParam,
            //    entityPredicateBody );
            //var expressionBody = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>( filterExpression, searchParam );

            //TODO: REPLACE WITH NEW EXPRESSION (expressionBody)
            searchExpressionList.Add( entityPredicateBody );
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have a string wrapped in single quotes (`'red shirt'`)? If you want to be able to extend it to accept multiple strings, you could use this as your function args: `(List<PropertyInfo> searchPropertiesList, SearchType searchType, params string[] args)`, then you'd just need to handle the 1 (or more) `args` that get passed in. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Zac. I'll look at updating or changing behaviour in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateSearchQuery<TEntity>(List<PropertyInfo> properties, string text, SearchType searchType = SearchType.Contains)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || properties == null || properties.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // For comparison
    //Expression<Func<ProductContainer, bool>> exp = q => searchText.Any(x => q.Product.ProductTitle.ToLower().Contains(x));

    var expressions = new List<Expression>();

    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "q");

    //search type
    var searchMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(searchType.ToString(), new[] { typeof(string) });

    //search terms
    var searchTerms = Expression.Constant(text.ToLower().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    //search param
    var str = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");

    foreach (var property in properties.Where(
        x => x.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>() == null))
    {
        var entityProperty = Expression.Property(entity, property);
        var toLower = Expression.Call(entityProperty, "ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
        var contains = Expression.Call(toLower, searchMethod, str);

        var anyExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(contains, str);

        var any = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(string) }, searchTerms, anyExpression);

        expressions.Add(any);
    }

    var ors = expressions.Aggregate((x, y) => Expression.Or(x, y));

    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(ors, entity);
    return exp;
}
```

I've put in `or` all the various expressions that are generated by the various properties (the `Aggregate` near the end of the method).